# Where does COMPASS expect to find the config.rb (if there are several)?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm introducing **COMPASS** to a project where we have different development branches from a SVN versioned web project in different folders for development. So we'll need to have several config.rb copies - the config.rb should be in trunk and thus in every branch we check out from SVN. How can I switch from "watching" the SASS directory in one branch checked out on my computer to watching another **SASS** directory in another branch checked out?!

Since the directory names for the checked out branched change with every new branch, having just one config.rb for **COMPASS** outside of / at the root directory of all branch directories is not an optimal solution since then we'd have to update every local config.rb on every developers computer with every new branch checked out...

Do I simply start "compass watch" in every branch's styles directory when working within that branch? Will there then be several **COMPASS** instances running, watching all the different branches?

I didn't find any answer to this problem on the internet, so I hope to find one here. Any idea welcome!

Cheers, Roman.

Comment: So the question is basically: Will COMPASS expect the config file - if not specified as a parameter, because the path will always differ with every new branch - generally in the same directory it has been invoked from? Will then several COMPASS instances run parallel if I call it two time from within two different project branch folders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can precise the location of the configuration file with the `-c` command line argument: `compass watch -c custom/folder/config.rb`. **But** be careful, all paths to match the configuration variables (`sass_dir`, `css_dir`, etc) depend on the initial path where the command Compass is launched. For example, you can place in a branch and point the configuration file present in the trunk.

However, the easiest way would be to have a configuration file by branch and start the compilation in each of them.

Comment: So if I understand you right I can use the same config for all branches (as long as the relative directories do not change) and just have to take care to launch compass from there, not outside the branches' directories, right?